# From a Java program, portable way to write strings with accents

Tags: java, windows, internationalization, portability, non-ascii-characters

Hullo,

I have a Java program, with command line interface. It is used on Linux and Windows. **The Java code is portable, and I want it to remain portable.**

My Java source files are in Unicode — which is good. In them, I have lines like this :

```
System.err.println("Paramètre manquant. … ");
```

I use Eclipse to **package** the program as a JAR archive.

Then, the program is run by a command like this :

`java -jar MyProgram.jar parameters`

In the Windows XP command line, this gives :

`ParamÞtre manquant. …`

**Is there a portable way to write strings with accents in the Java program, so that they appear correctly in the Windows command line ?** Or do we just have to live with Windows stupidly replacing accented E with icelandic thorn ?

I use Java 6.

Comment: Are you specifying the right `-encoding` option while compiling your code? See the [javac documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html) for details.

Comment: @mthmulders — Good idea, but Eclipse does not provide a way to do that. I choose Export… → Java → Runnable JAR file.

Answer (score 6):

In Java 1.6 you can use [System.console()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) instead of System.out.println() to display accentuated characters to console.

```
public class Test2 {
  public static void main(String args[]){
   String s = "caractères français :  à é \u00e9"; // Unicode for "é"
   System.out.println(s);
   System.console().writer().println(s);
  }
}
```

and the output is

```
C:\temp>java Test
caractþres franþais :  Ó Ú Ú
caractères français :  à é é
```

Comment: One thing to point out is, that typical Java IDEs (at least Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA) will throw NullPointerException, since System.console() is undefined when you work directly from IDE. The method is correct, anyway.

Comment: According to the Javadoc, this does not work in some situations, for example when the program is started by a job scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

Use unicode escaped sequence: `\u00E8`

```
System.err.println("Param\u00E8tre manquant. … ");
```

[Here's](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html) an useful Unicode character table.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not solve the problem, I get the same (bad) result in the Windows command prompt.

Comment: Whats the default charset of the system wwhere you run the code (`java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset()`)?

Comment: Alepac — I don't know, and I don't want to know. I want a **portable** development. There is no such thing as “the system where I run the code”. The program is run on Linux and Windows systems.

Comment: yes I agree. My solution is tipically portable but probably there is a problem on the environment you use

Answer (score 1):

Try using `\u<XXXX>` when encoding unicode characters. It won't look pretty in code, but it will work and be portable.

For instance:

```
String specialCharacters= "\u00E1 \u00E9 \u00ED \u00F3 \u00FA";
System.out.println(specialCharacters); // This will print á é í ó ú
```

Check Alepac's answer for a table of unicode characters.

Comment: No, it does not work. I get the same (bad) result in the Windows command prompt.

Comment: @Nicolas: That's because Windows console use different character encoding. And in most cases it is not even the same as Windows so-called code page, it is a DOS code page. `Console` class takes care about character encoding for you, `System.out` does not.